# Crystal Reports 8: Change the stored procedure used by a subreport?

Tags: stored-procedures, crystal-reports

Hi I'm using Crystal reports 8 and I need to change the stored procedure associated with a sub report, is it even possible? or I'm going have to redo it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) open the subreport in design view (right-click - edit subreport)
2) go to Database, Set Location
3) pick the new stored procedure to replace the existing one.

Done, although you may want to use Set Alias too so the old name doesn't persist in formulas.

I'm also assuming the new sp returns fields similar to the old one.

Comment: Yes sp returns a similar dataset. It's just has additional fields.